# What is the difference between an OS and a shell?

Tags: shell, operating-system

I know that shell takes executes the system commands typed in the command prompt.But is that it,is the shell only that much.I find the functions of an OS and shell to be very similar.Both are interfaces between the user and kernel.When does the OS interface show up and when does the shell interface show up.Thanks in advance

Comment: OS = Operating System (Windows, Linux, OSX...)

Comment: Same as the difference between your car and your steering wheel. One is the workhorse, one is the means of control.

Answer (score 1):

A shell is a *program* with whom you interact with the *operating system*.

The operating system implements several important abstractions:

- files†
- directories†
- processes
- networking‡
- users

to cite only a few ones. Thus the operating system is the piece software which is responsible for translating things like “the file `Buckaroo Banzai.mkv`” into things like ”that bunch of bytes sitting on that hard-drive connected on the SATA2 connector, which I am talking to through the chip 42 manufactured by Yoyodyne Corp.”

Now the operator using the computer needs an interface to express orders so that 
something actually happens with “files”, ”directories”, ”processes”, ”networking” and ”users”.  The shell is one of these interfaces, it is the traditional interface of UNIX systems. There is a second family of interfaces based on graphic interaction instead of text interaction. Famous examples are Microsoft Windows Explorer, Mac OS X Finder, but back in the late eighties, the Atari had Gem and the Amiga the Workbench. I cannot refrain to quote that text from Thomas Scoville, [The Elements Of Style: UNIX As Literature](http://theody.net/elements.html) which makes some important points about the differences between text and graphic interfaces.

When you use the *shell* you are interacting with the *operating system* through the *shell* and the various programs it allows you to run. The *shell* is an important part of the *operating system*, it is one of its interface, but it is distinct from the *operating system* itself.

†: read “filesystems”

‡: read “interprocess communication”

Answer (score 1):

A shell is simply a program. In Unix, a shell can be *any* program. Normally, a shell implements some kind of command interface (e.g., BASH, KSH, CSH). The shell can also be a graphical user interface that provides similar functions.

A shell can also be a specific appellation that restricts the user to certain features. For example, if you have point of sale system, you can configure an account so that the POS appellation is the shell, so all the user can do is POS stuff.